# FileUpload loses content on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a fileupload which loses its content on button click. I have a confirm button to freeze the page from user making any further changes. Once the changes are finalized, the button shall be renamed from Apply to Submit. But during this transition (Autopostback), fileupload loses its content.

To avoid this autopostback, I tried to fix this using javascript by freezing the textboxes and other controls but the button name doesn't change.

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=Submit.ClientID%>').value == "Apply") {
    ....
    document.getElementById('<%=Remarks.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('<%=Submit.ClientID%>').value == "Submit";
    return false;
}
return true;
```

I also tried to use the below code snippet but dint work either. In both the cases, the text boxes were disabled but the button name dint change.

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=Submit.ClientID%>').value == "Apply") {
    ....
    document.getElementById('<%=Remarks.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('<%=Submit.ClientID%>').innerHTML == "Submit";
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Have referred few sites but most of them suggest to use value or innerHTML. Not sure why it dint work here. Anything else am I missing?

Please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not an if you dont have to put `==` just one and you want to change the value.

change

```
document.getElementById('<%=Submit.ClientID%>').innerHTML == "Submit";
```

to

```
document.getElementById('<%=Submit.ClientID%>').value = "Submit";
```

Comment: Extremely my fault. Copied from the if block and pasted it. Thanks a tons.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to make sure that you load your JavaScript code after your button definition, or at the end of the file.

this is the correct form :

```
<button id="test"></button>
<script>

    var b = document.getElementById("test");
    b.innerHTML = "test" ;
</script>
```

not this :

```
<script>

    var b = document.getElementById("test");
    b.innerHTML = "test" ;
</script>
<button id="test"></button>
```

you can also use jQuery:

```
<button id="test"></button>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $("#test").text("test");
</script>
```

Comment: if the button is input he need to change the value not the text.